# Xamarin - Entry Focused and TapGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Spacing="0">
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="GoToBasket"></TapGestureRecognizer>
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <Frame x:Name="frmBasket" CornerRadius="24" Padding="8"  BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Entry x:Name="lblTotalBasket" TextChanged="lblTotalBasket_TextChanged" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding TotalPrice, StringFormat='₺{0:0.00}'}" Margin="0, 0, 5, 0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"></Entry>
            <Label x:Name="lblBasketIcon"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="&#xf291;" FontSize="15" TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}" Margin="8, 0, 0, 0"  FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

StackLayout TapGestureRecognizer working except Entry element. I tried add TapGestureRecognizer and Focused attribute for Entry element but also not worked.

How StackLayout TapGestureRecognizer does work on Entry element tap ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the `IsReadOnly=false` to entry, the TapGestureRecognizer won't work because it will get fouced when tap it and user can type something. In this cause, you can call your method in the `foucsed` event:

```
<Entry x:Name="lblTotalBasket" Focused="lblTotalBasket_Focused"/>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void lblTotalBasket_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("lblTotalBasket_Focused-entry");
}
```

If you set the `IsReadOnly=ture` to entry,  the TapGestureRecognizer will execute and you can also add TapGestureRecognizer to entry directly:

```
<Entry x:Name="lblTotalBasket" Focused="lblTotalBasket_Focused" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding TotalPrice, StringFormat='₺{0:0.00}'}" Margin="0, 0, 5, 0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
    <Entry.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
    </Entry.GestureRecognizers>
</Entry>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped-entry");
}
```

Update:

In Android, you also need to set `isEnable = false` to make `TapGestureRecognizer`  work:

```
<Entry x:Name="lblTotalBasket" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

Comment: isEnabled = "False" worked for me, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try setting TapGesture for parent control and for your entry set InputTransparent="True" so that when you tap on entry it will actually recognized as tap on parent control.